# ApiRTC - Behaviour with meshModeEnabled and meshOnlyEnabled

Tags: webrtc

I would like to know what is the exact behaviour of the Apizee PaaS when the `meshModeEnabled` and `meshOnlyEnabled` parameters are set to `true` ?

The documentation describes the usefulness of these 2 parameters but does not explain the behaviour in the Apizee application.

If we set the `meshModeEnabled` parameter to `true` and set the `meshOnlyEnabled` parameter to `true`, then this will prohibit ApiRTC from redirecting traffic to the SFU (to maintain a true Peer-To-peer).

My question is: by setting the two parameters mentioned above to true, the traffic will be exclusively P2P, which means that it is no longer possible to use the conversation recording system and the media retrieval with the API (because no passage to SFU)?

Thank you in advance

I have already used the 2 parameters but without any information on their technical behaviour on the Apizee PaaS side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for the ApiRTC lib release 4.7.8

> If we set the meshModeEnabled parameter to true and set the
> meshOnlyEnabled parameter to true, then this will prohibit ApiRTC from
> redirecting traffic to the SFU (to maintain a true Peer-To-peer).

You re right

> My question is: by setting the two parameters mentioned above to true,
> the traffic will be exclusively P2P, which means that it is no longer
> possible to use the conversation recording system and the media
> retrieval with the API (because no passage to SFU)?

I confirm. The SFU is needed for any activity that needs to centralize all the streams (recording, bandwith optimisation,...)

---

Beware that ApiRTC has a mecanism to choose the best stream routes depending of the use and of the bandwith quality of participant.

If you enable mesh mode,the behavior of ApiRTC will be:

- If < 5 participants AND session has not been in SFU mode before ==> `roomMode` = "mesh"
- If >= 5 participant OR someone join the room in SIP OR recording OR someone hase a doggy upload link OR session has been in SFU mode before ==> `roomMode` = SFU

Here are the default values if you don't specify any:

- meshModeEnabled : `false` ==> so by default it doesn't use the ApiRTC stream routing optimisation
- meshOnlyEnabled : `false`

To get the current connection mode, you can <strike>use the `apiCC.session.apiCCWebRTCClient.webRTCClient.MCUClient.sessionMCUs` object in your browser console.</strike> (unsupported) watch for the roomModeChanged of the current Conversation to be fired when the mode changes from mesh to SFU.

The `roomMode` attribute will show

- `"mesh"` => mesh mode
- or will not be defined => SFU mode

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have another request related here, I would be very grateful if you could take a look at it. Thank you very much -> [Media always sent to the cloud, even with meshOnlyEnabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74412423/apirtc-media-always-sent-to-the-cloud-even-with-meshonlyenabled)

Comment: Can you mark this one as answered please ? :)

Comment: Yes, of course :)