# ApiRTC - Media always sent to the cloud, even with meshOnlyEnabled

Tags: webrtc

As a follow-up to my previous post ([ApiRTC - Behaviour with meshModeEnabled and meshOnlyEnabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74361897/apirtc-behaviour-with-meshmodeenabled-and-meshonlyenabled))

Hello,

You say that SFU is necessary for any activity that requires centralizing all the streams (recording, bandwidth optimization,...). However, in MESH mode, the files/media exchanged still manage to be recorded on the Apizee media server even though I don't go through the SFU. How is this possible ?

Can this behaviour be disabled so that the exchanged documents never leave the MESH stream ?

I have not found anything about this in the documentation.

By the way, the documentation often mentions the term "MCU", does this mean that ApiRTC also uses an MCU server in addition to the SFU ?

Thanks in advance.

[apirtc](/questions/tagged/apirtc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can this behaviour be disabled so that the exchanged documents never
> leave the MESH stream ?

Concerning a recording of all the streams in the conversation (via the startRecording method of the Conversation object see https://apirtc.github.io/references/apirtc-js/Conversation.html#startRecording__anchor):
--> The composition of multiple streams into one video file is done server-side by the SFU (v4.4.8).

Concerning the files (through conversation.pushData method):
--> We manage the file transfer through uploading the file on a storage and share the URI to all parties of a conversation. P2P transfer is not available (v4.4.8)

To exchange data in a P2P mode, you can use the Conversation.sendData method to send raw data across all participants.

Regarding your question about the MCU, no, ApiRTC doesnt use any MCU server to date (v. 4.4.8). The document refers to MCU for very specific on-premise deployment, not supported for ApiRTC users.

Cheers,

Romain

Comment: Thank you very much for all these clarifications :)